# Building Tensorflow 2.0 from source

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, build, bazel

I've built Tensorflow 2.0 from source using the below commands:

```
-march=native -Wno-sign-compare -mssse3 -mcx16 -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mpopcnt -mno-avx

bazel build --config=opt  //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --local_ram_resources=1024 --jobs=1 --define=tf_api_version=2
```

The build apparently completed successfully, that is without any errors, but when I go to install, using the below command:

```
python /tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py install
```

It installs the egg in site-packages and checks for dependencies, but does nothing else. Nor does it return any error. The end of the output is below:

```
Searching for Markdown==3.1.1
Best match: Markdown 3.1.1
Adding Markdown 3.1.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing markdown_py script to /var/...

Using /var/.../python3.6/site-packages
Searching for h5py==2.9.0
Best match: h5py 2.9.0
Adding h5py 2.9.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /var/.../python3.6/site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for tensorflow==2.0.0rc0
```

and of course when I run python:

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment at the moment. Can you verify the installation is done successfully ? That is after running:

```
python /tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py install
```

you can check the folder tensorflow package in Python lib folders.